# Need help calculating this limit for $\varepsilon \to 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I used Gauss' identity to derive

$$(\ast) {1\over \varepsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS = {1\over r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(a,r)} f dS $$

where $0<\varepsilon<r$ and $f$ is harmonic and $B(a,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ around $a$.

Now I want to use this to prove that

$$ f(a) = {1\over |\partial B(a,r)|}\int_{\partial B(a,r)} f dS$$

Hence my question:

> How to calculate  $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}{1\over \varepsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS$?

Does $ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}{1\over \varepsilon^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B(a,\varepsilon)} f dS = f(a)$? (I'm not sure what the value of $|\partial B(a,r)|$ is in higher dimensions, I believe it is the surface are of the sphere so I am also missing a factor on the RHS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scaled by the surface area, you do indeed get $f(a)$. Roughly speaking this is because you have an average of values all of which are being made arbitrarily close to $f(a)$. Precisely speaking you can say essentially the same thing: given $\varepsilon$, find $\delta$ so that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$. Then for $r<\delta$, the average of $f$ over the sphere is $f(a)$ plus the average of $g(x)$, which is at most $\varepsilon$ in magnitude. So the average of $f$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $f(a)$.

Scaling only by $r^{n-1}$ as you are, let $\sigma_n$ be the surface area of the unit sphere. Then I'll show the limit is $\sigma_n f(a)$ as follows:

$$\left |-\sigma_n f(a)+\frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} f(x) dS(x) \right | = \left | -\sigma_n f(a) + \frac{\sigma_n}{|\partial B(a,r)|} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} (f(a) + g(x)) dS(x) \right | \\
= \left | -\sigma_n f(a) + \frac{\sigma_n |\partial B(a,r)| f(a)}{|\partial B(a,r)|}  + \frac{\sigma_n}{|\partial B(a,r)|} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} g(x) dS(x) \right | \\
\leq \frac{\sigma_n}{|\partial B(a,r)|} \int_{\partial B(a,r)} |g(x)| dS(x) \\
\leq \frac{\sigma_n \varepsilon |\partial B(a,r)|}{|\partial B(a,r)|}$$

provided $r<\delta$ as defined in the first paragraph.

Comment: What is the definition of "the average of $f$ over the sphere"?

Comment: @user174981 The integral of $f$ against the surface measure on the sphere, divided by the surface area of the sphere.

Comment: But the scaling in my derived equation isn't the surface area: or is $|\partial B(a,r)| = r^{1-n}$? It doesn't look right.

Comment: The surface area can be written as $\sigma_n r^{n-1}$ where $\sigma_n$ is the area of the unit sphere in dimension $n$ (for example, $\sigma_2=4 \pi$). So your expression converges to $\sigma_n f(a)$.

Comment: I don't understand: you seem to be talking about two different things which are both surface areas of the sphere. One surface area of the sphere is $\sigma_n r^{n-1}$ and another surface area of the sphere is $\sigma_n$?

Comment: @user174981 The surface area of a general sphere is $\sigma_n r^{n-1}$. The surface area of the *unit* sphere is $\sigma_n$, which is a dimension-dependent constant. One way to calculate $\sigma_n$ is given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area

Comment: Ok. That cleared up one confusion, thank you. But I still don't understand how to calculate the limit of $\varepsilon \to 0$....

Comment: @user174981 See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit, I understand now everything! Thank you!

Comment: How do you avoid the problem that $\delta$ may force $r$ to be smaller than $\varepsilon$? We fix $0<\varepsilon<r$ at the beginning. Then you find $\delta$. But what if $\delta<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user174981 (\*) holds for *any* $0<\varepsilon \leq r$. That is, the average over the sphere of radius $r$ does not depend on $r$, provided $f$ is harmonic on the largest relevant ball. So this isn't a problem. The only problem is computing the limit.

Comment: You are right. I confused myself, I'm sorry. What I still don't understand is: where in the calculation of the limit do you use $(\ast)$?

Comment: @user174981 In calculating the limit we never actually use (\*). (\*) gets used so that we can conclude that the average over a sphere with finite radius is actually equal to $f(a)$. In other words, if $M(r)$ is the average over the sphere with radius $r$, then (\*) shows that $M$ is constant on $(0,R)$ for some $R>0$. Then we compute the limit and extend $M$ continuously. Now $M$ is still constant, so $M(r) \equiv M(0)=f(a)$, which is what we originally wanted to prove.

Comment: @user174981 It may help to note that $M(0)=f(a)$ does not depend on the fact that $f$ is harmonic. We would still have that if $f$ were merely continuous. The fact that $f$ is harmonic just lets us say that $M$ is constant.